# OpenShift - How to use unicorn instead of Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, openshift

How can I tell OpenShift to deploy my app using unicorn instead of its own server (Passenger I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today it would require implementing a custom cartridge - see this cartridge https://github.com/pbrazdil/openshift-advanced-ruby-cartridge for a description.